# No dropdown in accounts-ui-bootstrap-3

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I've added the accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 package to my Meteor app, but can't seem to get the dropdown to work. I'm using the following packages:

standard-app-packages

insecure

preserve-inputs

iron-router

http

tags

bootstrap-3

accounts-ui-bootstrap-3

accounts-password

accounts-twitter

Here's a link to the repo for reference - https://github.com/Ja5onHoffman/mRoute

And the template in which the {{loginButtons}} tag exists:

```
<template name="navBar">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar nav">
      <li><a href="{{pathFor 'homeTemplate'}}">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{pathFor 'aboutPage'}}">About</a></li>
    </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        {{>_loginButtons }}
        </ul>
  </div>
</div> 
</nav>
</template>
```

I'm not sure where the source of the problem lies, so please let me know if you'd like me to post other sections of code.

Comment: What version of meteor are you running? I'm experiencing the same problem with V 0.8

Comment: I updated to 0.8 and am still having the problem. The link shows but no dropdown.

Comment: I've got a solution below, but it's not pretty

Comment: Made a little progress here. The .dropdown-menu class contains a display: none attribute in two separate places when the dropdown is rendered. If you turn this off in dev tools it shows, not sure how to change this in the accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 files though since none of the .styl files contain a display: none for .dropdown-menu.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue before and I found out a solution for myself. just run `mrt remove bootstrap` and `meteor remove bootstrap`. If you have the same issue. That may help out.

Comment: Had the same problem because of `useraccounts:bootstrap` package conflicting with this package.

Answer (score 1):

Use accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 blaze branch and {{>_loginButtons }}

---

Updated to show **smart.json**:

```
{ "packages": {
    "spin": {},
    "bootstrap-3": {},
    "iron-router-progress": {
      "git": "https://github.com/Multiply/iron-router-progress.git",
      "branch": "blaze-integration"
    },
    "fullcalendar": {},
    "moment": {},
    "bootstrap-3-timepicker": {},
    "iron-router": {},
    "accounts-ui-bootstrap-3": {
      "git": "https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3",
      "branch": "blaze"
    },
    "mailgun-api": {},
    "paypal": {},
    "roles": {},
    "autocomplete": {}
  }
}
```

Also perform a Meteor update afterwards

Comment: Is there anything to do with `_` , i think {{> loginButtons }} is enough

Comment: @iAmME It said to use the _ in that blaze layout I believe. It is working for me. I think I was getting an error in the console referring to Spark otherwise.

Comment: @JHof Don't know what to tell you. I'll edit my response to show you my smart.json order

Comment: Revisiting this. With @Chris's changes and smart.json the Sign In/Up link shows, but it's unstyled and the dropdown doesn't appear on click. Anyone else

Comment: @JHof I'm now experiencing the same problems on other apps

Comment: @JHof make sure you don't have accounts-ui installed by runnung
`mrt remove accounts-ui`

Answer (score 1):

This is a temporary and ugly solution. Yuck.

1. Visit [Bootstrap-Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)
2. Make a custom Bootstrap with only dropdown.js included
3. Copy content of said file into a js file in your Clients directory, such as */Client/main.js*
4. Admit this is a very ugly patch, but keep developing